# xsl namespace problem

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

If I have this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match='/'>
      <xsl:value-of select="//Description" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this XML

```
<ArrayOfLookupValue xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>AGL</Description>
    <Value>8</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>Australian Power &amp; Gas</Description>
    <Value>6</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>EnergyAustralia</Description>
    <Value>13</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>Origin Energy</Description>
    <Value>9</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>TRU Energy</Description>
    <Value>7</Value>
  </LookupValue>
</ArrayOfLookupValue>
```

How do I actually get some data from this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Description" />
```

I have spent hours on this and I have come to the conclusion that the xmlns= namespace is what is causing me grief.

Any help greatly appreciated.

BTW the XML is coming from a web service so I can't just "change" it - I can preprocess it but that isn't ideal...

Also I have confirmed that removing the namespaces from a mock of the XML does fix the problem.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a short and easy solution.

Comment: You are right that the namespace is making the difference. See Dimitre's good explanation... and you will really save yourself time in the future if you read up on XML namespaces (particularly, as used in XPath).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This is the most FAQ for both XPath and XSLT**.

**The short answer is** that in XPath an unprefixed name is considered to belong to "no namespace". However, in a document with a default namespace the unprefixed names belong to the default namespace.

**Therefore, for such document the expression**

```
//Description
```

**selects nothing** (because there is no `Description` (or any other) element in the document that belongs to "no namespace" -- all element names belong to the default namespace).

**Solution**:

Define a namespace in your XSLT that has the same `namespace-uri()` as the default namespace of the XML document. Then use the prefix of the so defined namespace for any name used in an Xpath expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://switchwise.com.au/">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match='/'>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//x:Description" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<ArrayOfLookupValue xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>AGL</Description>
    <Value>8</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>Australian Power &amp; Gas</Description>
    <Value>6</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>EnergyAustralia</Description>
    <Value>13</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>Origin Energy</Description>
    <Value>9</Value>
  </LookupValue>
  <LookupValue>
    <Description>TRU Energy</Description>
    <Value>7</Value>
  </LookupValue>
</ArrayOfLookupValue>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Description xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>AGL</Description>
<Description xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>Australian Power &amp; Gas</Description>
<Description xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>EnergyAustralia</Description>
<Description xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>Origin Energy</Description>
<Description xmlns="http://switchwise.com.au/"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>TRU Energy</Description>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. How do you mark a question as being an FAQ by the way?

Comment: @LarsH: I don't think there is a way to mark a question as a FAQ -- at present the FAQ are determined by the numbers of views they have -- that is actually "Most Viewed". And what we need is not FAQ bat FAT -- frequently asked topics :)

Comment: LOL - How easy it that when you know how!!! Thank you so much for such a simple, easy to understand answer, I have put these changes into my XSL and it's working as hoped. Thanks again!!

Comment: 2016 and still relevant. Where were you hours ago, lol. Thank you for the question and answer!

Comment: @emptywalls, Unfortunately true. I believe this "feature" is one of the main reasons that not many people understand and use XML.